# EMFILE error in react(vite and lerna) app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

[image]I have a react app, created with lerna and vite and I use tailwind css for ui, but I face this error when I want to run my app (on windows):

[image: react EMFILE error]

I don't know how to fix the internal server error , too many files open problem
I tried to re-install node-module but it seems to be tailwind problem